# Multivariate normal distribution from invertable covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, normal-distribution

I want to generate a random vector with $\mathcal{N}(0, C)$ distribution, i.e. normal distribution with $0$ mean and given covariance matrix $C$.

$C$ is not invertible (singular). [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) it's written:

> The covariance matrix **is allowed to be singular** (in which case the corresponding distribution has no density). This case arises frequently in statistics (...)

So, how can I do it without inverting $C$?

Comment: You mean **not** invertible.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for a vector $BX$ with covariance matrix $C$.

$C[BX]=E(BX⋅BX^T)=E(BX⋅X^T⋅B^T)= B⋅E(XX^T)⋅B^T = BIB^T = BB^T$

So, we get matrix $B$ straight from matrix $C$, decomposing it to $BB^T$.

For this we can use [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) or, when $C$ is positive definite, 
[Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $B$ is a matrix and $X$ is a  normal random vector with covariance matrix $I$, what is the covariance matrix of $BX$?

Comment: Is it simply $BI$?

Comment: No, it isn't.  Use the definition of covariance matrix in terms of expected value.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate covariance matrix of a... matrix, which $BX$ unfortunately is...

Comment: $X$ is a vector.  $B$ is a matrix.  $BX$ is a vector (it is assumed that the sizes are appropriate so the multiplication can be done).

Comment: $\mathbf{C}[BX] \triangleq E\{(\mathbf{BX}-\bar{\mathbf{BX}})(\mathbf{BX}-\bar{\mathbf{BX}})^T\}$ But I don't know what next.

Comment: Expand and use linearity.  Or for simplicity you can assume the mean is $\bf 0$.  Note that $\bf B$ is not random.

Comment: $C[BX] = E(BX \cdot BX^T) = E(BX \cdot X^T \cdot B^T) = E(BX \cdot X^T)B^T$ and I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: $E[X X^T] = I$

Comment: $E[BXX^T]B^T = B \cdot E[XX^T]B^T = BIB^T$? :)

Comment: Please give me an answer how to do it, no tips, you see I'm a greenhorn in this area.

Comment: $I$ is the identity matrix, so $BIB^T = B B^T$.  So you want to find a matrix $B$ with $B B^T = C$.  For example, you could look up the Cholesky decomposition.